# How to retain the state even after refreshing the browser the in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically i want to main the state of the component even after refreshing. Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import tips from './tips';
import PivotTableUI from 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI';
import PivotTable from 'react-pivottable/PivotTable';
import 'react-pivottable/pivottable.css';
import TableRenderers from 'react-pivottable/TableRenderers';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import createPlotlyRenderers from 'react-pivottable/PlotlyRenderers';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const PlotlyRenderers = createPlotlyRenderers(Plot);


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    pivotState: {
      data:  [["Name", "CreationDate"]],
      rows: ['Name'],
      cols: ['Humanize'],
      aggregatorName: 'Count',
      rendererName: 'Grouped Column Chart',
  plotlyOptions: {width: 500, height: 500}
  }
  };

 handleClick = () => {
                this.setState(
                  {
                    pivotState: {
                      data: tips,
                      rows: ['Payer Gender'],
                      cols: ['Party Size'],
                      aggregatorName: 'Count',
                      rendererName: 'Grouped Column Chart',
                  plotlyOptions: {width: 600, height: 500}
                  }
                  });
        }

    componentDidMount() {
          const previous state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "pivotstate" ) );  --> It didnt worked
          }

render() {
    //console.log(this.state)
  return (
    <div styles="width=50px">
      <PivotTable
               //  data={this.state.pullResults.body || []}
                onChange={s => this.setState({pivotState: s})}
                renderers={Object.assign({}, TableRenderers, PlotlyRenderers)}
                {...this.state.pivotState}
            />


      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get results</button>
    </div>

  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My tips data file

```
  ["Total Bill","Tip","Payer Gender","Payer Smoker","Day of Week","Meal","Party Size"],
    [16.99,1.01,"Female","Non-Smoker","Sunday","Dinner",2],
    [10.34,1.66,"Male","Non-Smoker","Sunday","Dinner",3],
    [21.01,3.5,"Male","Non-Smoker","Sunday","Dinner",3],
    [23.68,3.31,"Male","Non-Smoker","Sunday","Dinner",2],
    [24.59,3.61,"Female","Non-Smoker","Sunday","Dinner",4],
    [25.29,4.71,"Male","Non-Smoker","Sunday","Dinner",4] ]
```

Above code will show me the empty graph in the DOM first and after hitting button it will render the results.
These results are perishing after refresh but i want to retain them even after refresh . The update should happen only after i hit the Button.

I know i need to use `localstorage` for this. In localstorage i need to pass the state as JSON.stringify something like this `JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "pivotstate" ) );` i had kept this localstorage step in `componentDidMount` but i dont know how to pass `pivotstate` here.

Reference [for the source](https://github.com/plotly/react-pivottable)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to use `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount` life cycle and `beforeunload` event listener rather than updating local storage on each update

```
setStateToLocalStorage = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(this.state));
  window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.setStateToLocalStorage);
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.setStateToLocalStorage);
  this.setState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.setStateToLocalStorage();
}
```

So both of your setting and getting will be triggered only once.

Since a page refresh does not call `componentWillUnmount`. We have also added a event listener that listens for page refresh.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkw9xo8qkr) is an example

Comment: @Private if the answer helped you, please select this as the right answer. So that others searching for the same issue know what course of action to take

Comment: Thanks Prasanna in the past comment i had mentioned the same graph is coming in both the pages , the problem is i am updating the same state . The below answer too solves my problem. Since i cant accept both the answers. I will answer the best one by EOD.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method

```
componentDidMount() {
  let state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myState'));
  this.setState(state);

}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

  if (isDiff(this.state, prevState)) {
    localStorage.setItem('myState', JSON.stringify(this.state));
  }

}
```

every time when state changes, compare current state with previous state, if they are different, save current state to localStorage

here is a simple dumb diff function implementaion:

```
function isDiff(a,b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) !== JSON.stringify(b);
}
```